# Cassandra Failed to Update Shard

Tags: cassandra, sharding

Hi i'm using Temporal service framework to orchestrate workflow process and cassandra database as datastore to record the workflow stateful process.
My temporal is getting error when trying to update shard with detail as follow:

`{"level":"error","ts":"2024-02-02T02:54:57.744Z","msg":"Persistent store operation failure","service":"history","shard-id":32,"address":"10.59.68.74:7234","shard-item":"0xc00277ea00","store-operation":"update-shard","error":"Failed to update shard.  previous_range_id: 30415, columns: (range_id=30414)","shard-range-id":30416,"previous-shard-range-id":30415,"logging-call-at":"context_impl.go:732"}`

Do you have any experience on how to deal with this?